# Automatically Setting a Devise User as a Stripe Customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, stripe-payments

My strategy is this:

1. Have a user sign up
2. Automatically associate that user to a Stripe ID

How I've tried to implement this:

I created a Users controller and have it inherit from the RegistrationController:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users'}
```

I created a callback after a user is saved:

```
after_save :set_stripe_customer_id

private
def set_stripe_customer_id
end
```

Now, what I think needs to be here is something like:

```
current_user.update_attribute(:stripe_id => ....
```

The docs show code like

```
Stripe::Customer.create(
  :description => "Customer for test@example.com",
  :card => "tok_1046el4BfU4hLNTvxYcIz4rE"
)
```

Thing is, I don't want my customer to necessarily put his card in immediately. Although, this isn't a big deal, I'm fine with waiting to require registration until the actual point of purchase. My question is what is the simplest, bare minimum code I need to make my callback automatically create a Stripe customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the parameters to `Stripe::Customer.create` are optional, so you can do something as bare-bones as:

```
def set_stripe_customer_id
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create
  current_user.update_attributes :stripe_id => customer.id
end
```

And then later on make then a subscription for that customer, or update the various details as you need.

Although I would say this isn't really necessary. There's no real downside to waiting until you actually need the customer to make it (eg, because they are subscribing).